# User authentication in django_webtest

Tags: django, django-testing

I have following code in my template:

```
<div class="account">
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url settings %}"
       class="iconed username">{{ request.user.username }}</a>
    &nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <a href="{% url logout %}?next={{ request.path }}"
       class="iconed logout">{% trans "Logout" %}</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url login %}?next={{ request.path }}" class="iconed login">{% trans "Login" %}</a>
    &nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <a href="{% url sign_up %}?next={{ request.path }}"
       class="iconed sign-up">{% trans "Sign up" %}</a>
{% endif %}
</div>
```

As you can see, it shows different links depends on user logged in or not. It works fine if I test it by hands, but when I try to test it with following code:

```
def test_home_logged_in(self):
    if self.client.login(username='Test', password='secret'):
        home = self.app.get('/')
        self.assertOK(home)
        self.assertContains(home, '/settings/')
        self.assertContains(home, '/logout/')
    else:
        self.fail("Couldn't log in.")
```

*login()* returns True, but test fails. I called showbrowser() for home object and see, that page that was returned, looks like page for anonymous user - it contains links to sign up and login besides links to settings and logout.

Is it correct to use *request.user.is_authenticated* in template to check if user is authenticated? Why template doesn't see that user was signed up from **test**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on your other questions, I'm guessing you're using [django_webtest](https://bitbucket.org/kmike/django-webtest). If so, you can specify to the request which user you want to be logged in as. So to access the homepage as user 'Test' you would do:

```
home = self.app.get('/', user='Test')
```

Comment: It works! I tried this method before, but send object as user. Thanks a lot, @Spike, you come to my help again!

Answer (score 2):

It is correct, but you need to have [`django.core.context_processors.request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) in [`settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) to make `request` accessible from templates.

Comment: Thanks, @jkbr, but I already have this context processor in settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS. Problem appears only when I try to access template from test case.

Comment: What does `self.app.get('/')` do as opposed to `self.client.get`?

Comment: I forgot to write, that I use *django_webtest* as testing framework, sorry. Thanks for your reply, self.client.get('/') works fine after authentication.